# How to change Idle time on the Wordpress admin dashboard?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a fresh installation of Wordpress 5.9, I installed the WPVivid plugin to restore from backup. However, the restoration process seems to take more than 15 mins but wordpress keeps logging me out with a popup message that says "session expired".
How do I change that?, or maybe increase the idle timeout?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code it

```
add_filter('auth_cookie_expiration', 'ak_function', 99, 3);
function ak_function($seconds, $user_id, $sesstiontime){
    
    if ( $sesstiontime) {       
        $expiration = 14*24*60*60;
    } else {
          $expiration = 2*24*60*60; //UPDATE HERE;
    }
    if ( PHP_INT_MAX - time() < $expiration ) {
        $expiration =  PHP_INT_MAX - time() - 5;
    }

    return $expiration;
}
```

or

```
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year' );
function keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year( $expirein ) {
    return YEAR_IN_SECONDS; // 1 year in seconds
}
```